# Upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 to Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2011, 2013, upgrade

We are upgrading from Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 to Tridion 2013 SP1. So we are referring to the Tridion 2013 SP1 DLL to the solution in the Visual Studio. After adding the latest DLL build the solution which is giving the following warnings.

1. 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem.GetItems(Tridion.ContentManager.Filter)' is obsolete: 'Deprecated method. Use GetItems() or GetItems(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter) instead.'
2. 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.BinaryContent.FileSize' is obsolete: 'Use Size property   instead. This property can't handle size more than 2GB.'

These warnings related to the deprecated still I'm worried whether these warnings will affect us or not? If yes, then how to resolve these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will not affect now.
Tridion just give you know that this methods can be deleted in the next releases(and they will be deleted, just don't know in which release exactly).
So it is better to use provided analogs...If you will use your code in next releases, probably your code will not compiled.

Comment: If this suggestion was useful, please click the up arrow button to the left of it. If it was the answer to your question, please click the check mark.

Comment: @Syav4eg can you please let us know what are the provided analogs to use

Comment: They are mentioned in the message: "Use GetItems() or GetItems(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter) instead."
"Use Size property instead"